# Flutter, bug in classes

Tags: flutter, dart

In `main.dart` I call `Quiz`'s function `getQuestionText` and `getQuestionAnswer`, `getQuestionText` works as expected but the other doesn't work, if returns me always the first result of the list. I just placed a `debugPrint()` and as expected `getQuestionText()` prints the correct number, `getQuestionAnswer()` always print `0`, how is that possible?

```
class Quiz {
  int _questionNumber = 0;

  List<Question> _questions = [
    Question('Some cats are actually allergic to humans', true),
    Question('You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', false),
  ];

  void nextQuestion() {
    if (_questionNumber < _questions.length - 1) {
      _questionNumber++;
    }
  }

  String getQuestionText() {
    print('$_questionNumber'); // <-- print the correct number
    return _questions[_questionNumber].questionText;
  }

  bool getQuestionAnswer() {
    print('$_questionNumber'); // <-- always print 0
    return _questions[_questionNumber].questionAnswer;
  }
}
```

Here how I call the functions

```
void checkAnswer(bool userAnswer) {
    bool correctAnswer = Quiz().getQuestionAnswer();

    setState(() {

      if (userAnswer == correctAnswer) {
        // right answer
      } else {
          // wrong pick
        );
      }
      quiz.nextQuestion();
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us how your _calling_ this class/function?

Comment: @MendelG I simplified a little bit but that's how I've done

Comment: I think the problems in this line: `bool correctAnswer = Quiz().getQuestionAnswer();` you keep on createing a _new_ instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you always create a fresh instance of your class `Quiz` by calling `bool correctAnswer = Quiz().getQuestionAnswer();` inside `checkAnswer()`.

Try to store the `Quiz` instance ouside:

```dart
const myQuiz = Quiz();

void checkAnswer(bool userAnswer) {
  bool correctAnswer = myQuiz.getQuestionAnswer();

  setState(() {
    if (userAnswer == correctAnswer) {
      // right answer
    } else {
      // wrong pick
    }

    myQuiz.nextQuestion();
  });
}
```